# hide buttons from jw player

Tags: jwplayer

i want to hide buttons from jw player
stop button and timeline

i am using jwplayer 4.3

Answer (score 4):

You can look at http://developer.longtailvideo.com/trac/wiki/SkinningThePlayer for how to skin the player.

And you can use flashvar ( http://developer.longtailvideo.com/trac/wiki/Player4FlashVars )  `controlbar=none`to remove the bar completely..